# Calculate Variance of Whole Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, data-science, dask

I have a dask dataframe like this:

```
pprint(daskdf.iloc[:,95:100].head())
   1980-04-02  1980-04-03  1980-04-04  1980-04-05  1980-04-06
0    3.459240         0.0    2.296430    5.771730   13.344725
1    5.036489         0.0    1.021041    3.930686    8.015582
2    0.000000         0.0    0.667812    4.580948    9.824745
3    0.000000         0.0    0.708841    5.247479   10.690757
4    0.000000         0.0    0.293334    4.057512    9.703477
```

In pandas, to calculate the variance of the whole dataframe I'd use the stack function as follows (I'm only using 5 columns as an example to show what the data looks like):

```
data.iloc[:,95:100].stack().var()
Out[50]: 21.58617875939196
```

However, I can't do this in dask, and I can't stack a pandas dataframe and then convert to dask as dask doesn't support multidimensional indexes. Using .var().mean().compute() also doesn't calculate the same statistic. How can I calculate the variance of the whole dataset and/or use the stack function in dask?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use the `var` function of Dask arrays

```
df.values.var()
```